# Sql Logs Warning No active database connections in cakephp debugkit

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.3

I have installed the debugkit plugin of CakePHP. The debugkit icon is displaying on the top right side of the website.
I am facing an issue. The debugkit showing this message.

Sql Logs

Warning No active database connections

but the website is running fine. Please help i want to see SQL log from debugkit.
Please note Configure::write('debug', 3); is already set to three.

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed all the steps necessary to get debugkit properly up and running?  Note the fifth and final step under Installation from the directions on the [debug kit page](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit) on github - "Make sure to remove the sql_dump element from your layout"

The reason for this being that the sql_dump will consume log entries before they get to debug_kit, leaving debug_kit with nothing to render (the underlying code for this can be seen [here](http://thechaw.com/debug_kit/source/views/elements/sql_log_panel.ctp) from line 12 on down - where debug_kit checks for content and if it finds none, returns the error message that you are experiencing).

So to summarize, check to see if you have removed the sql_dump element - most likely located at

```
app/View/Layouts/default.ctp
```

**Note**
When posting a question please be sure to include the steps you have taken to research the issue up to this point.  This will help you to get the most detailed and relevant answers.